# How to import python library as a zip file?

Tags: python

I am trying to import the python request library from a zip file. (Because I am trying to use AWS Lambda Layer). I keep having the issue that "No module called No module named 'requests'" even though I put the zip file of the library under the right place. My question is since the module is more like a py file without .py, how could the library work without 'request.py' in inside the tar.gz? I have no idea why the library is working fine on local machine.

Comment: zip and tar.gz aren't the same thing.  Which is it?

Comment: @Valentino Thank you so much. I've searched for the problem and get nothing.